# How to calculate rate in HTML web app

Tags: google-apps-script

How to calculate rate using some formulas in HTML web app

I have created html web app in google script in this form i am trying to provide an option to generate a rate of services (More like calculator- using multiplication function )

I have attached the html script when user enter the time in "Number Of Hours" Tab (C) function should run and it should multiply with "Per Hour Rate" and should reflect in "D"(Total Rate)

Also, it should reflect the total rate in Grand Total Tab

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img src="" alt="IIFL LOGO" style="width:100px;height:50px;">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
       <p class="navbar-text"></p>
       <p class="navbar-text"> </p>
       <li class="active"><a >Technology Team-Project Proposal Form</a></li>
   
      <p class="navbar-text">      </p>
      <p class="navbar-text">      </p>
      <p class="navbar-text">      </p>

    </ul>
    
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" onsubmit="return searchRequest();">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="requestID" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Requset Number">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="updateRequest()" id="updateBtn" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      <a href="https://script.google.com/a/macros/iifl.com/s/AKfycbyR7BzkYpbt2EKkIdoViJO1ZshPCXs9TBPv4P2eJGs/dev" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Refresh</a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Project Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="requestNumber"></div>
</div>
 <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Service Area</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Service Area"type="text" placeholder="Manager" disabled></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Per Hour Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Per Hour Rate"type="text" placeholder="500" disabled></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Number Of Hours</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rTpe"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Total Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rFor"></div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Service Area</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Service Area"type="text" placeholder="Project  Manager" disabled></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Per Hour Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Per Hour Rate"type="text" placeholder="300" disabled></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Number Of Hours</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rTpe"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Total Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rFor"></div>
</div>
 <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Grand Total Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rFor"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success active" onclick="updateRequest()" id="updateBtn" class="center">Save</button>    
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below code...

```js
    
    $("#rTpe1").keyup(function(e){
      $("#rFor1").val(this.value * $("#PerHourRate1").val());
      $("#rFor3").val( Number($("#rFor1").val()) + Number($("#rFor2").val()))
    });
    
    $("#rTpe2").keyup(function(e){
      $("#rFor2").val(this.value * $("#PerHourRate2").val());
      $("#rFor3").val( Number($("#rFor1").val()) + Number($("#rFor2").val()))
    });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <img src="" alt="IIFL LOGO" style="width:100px;height:50px;">
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
           <p class="navbar-text"></p>
           <p class="navbar-text"> </p>
           <li class="active"><a >Technology Team-Project Proposal Form</a></li>
       
          <p class="navbar-text">      </p>
          <p class="navbar-text">      </p>
          <p class="navbar-text">      </p>
    
        </ul>
        
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" onsubmit="return searchRequest();">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="requestID" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Requset Number">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="updateRequest()" id="updateBtn" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
          <a href="https://script.google.com/a/macros/iifl.com/s/AKfycbyR7BzkYpbt2EKkIdoViJO1ZshPCXs9TBPv4P2eJGs/dev" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Refresh</a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Project Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="requestNumber"></div>
    </div>
     <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Service Area</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Service Area"type="text" placeholder="Manager" disabled></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Per Hour Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="PerHourRate1"type="text" value="500" readonly></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Number Of Hours</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rTpe1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Total Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rFor1"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Service Area</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Service Area"type="text" placeholder="Project  Manager" disabled></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Per Hour Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="PerHourRate2"type="text" value="300" readonly></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Number Of Hours</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rTpe2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Total Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rFor2"></div>
    </div>
     <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Grand Total Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rFor3" readonly></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success active" onclick="updateRequest()" id="updateBtn" class="center">Save</button>    
    </div>
    </div>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Riz
Help me to align below button in Left side

<div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Grand Total Rate</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rFor3" readonly></div>

Comment: Thanks, Riz for Script ... :) 
I have fixed the HTML align issue... please ignore the above comment